# php processes owned by ppid 1 after X amount of time

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

I have a CentOS server running WHM that uses FastCGI (`mod_fcgid`) running PHP 5.2.17 on Apache 2.0 with SuExec. When I start Apache it begins fine and serving requests. If I run `ps` on the terminal as root I see the `php` processes and they are owned by their `httpd` parent processes.

After X amount of time - different from time to time, not much longer than a few hours typically - the server will begin spawning PHP jobs owned by the init process ID (`1`)

Example of good listing:

```
12918 18254 /usr/bin/php
12918 18257 /usr/bin/php
12918 18293 /usr/bin/php
12918 18545 /usr/bin/php
12918 18546 /usr/bin/php
12918 19016 /usr/bin/php
12918 19948 /usr/bin/php
```

Then later something like:

```
1  6800 /usr/bin/php 
1  6801 /usr/bin/php 
1  7036 /usr/bin/php 
1  8788 /usr/bin/php 
1 10488 /usr/bin/php  
1 10571 /usr/bin/php  
1 10572 /usr/bin/php
```

The `php` processes running owned by (`1`) never get cleaned up. Why would these processes be running? We don't use `setsid` or anything beyond basic PHP in the code this server is running.

Cheers & Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the parent processes of these processes died but they themselves did not terminate so they have become orphans and thus adopted by process 1, i.e., init. the software usually has problems when this happens a lot, and you may want to consider upgrade to a newer version.